# How do I delete the "Apps" bookmark in my bookmark bar?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

The new Chrome update added an **Apps** bookmark to my bookmarks bar. It doesn't let me delete it, as the **Delete** option is greyed out.

[image: Greyed out delete option]

Clicking it doesn't show the gold star button like other bookmarks:

[image: Gold star not appearing]

I **never** use any apps on chrome - It's basically a link to a url. So I don't care if that's removed forever.

How do I remove it?

Comment: You could just untick the Show apps shortcut option

Answer (score 113, accepted):

The option you are looking for is in the menu you've shown a picture of.
Simply uncheck "Show Apps Shortcut" to remove it.

Comment: So simple and we did not notice...
Thank you!

Comment: I always wanted to get rid of it. I've right-clicked it many times but, just like OP, I see delete option disabled. Now, I searched for it today. Was it really that simple? I'm pissed.

Comment: lol i cant believe i missed it as well... looks like it is time to visit the eye doctor again ;)

Answer (score 4):

Right-click the bookmark bar and unselect it.

Pretty lame on the part of Google.

They could have done a less invasive way of promoting their software.